# How can I dissolve problem with convert For loop to R function?

Tags: r

when I made for loop to calculate shapiro test of each row of matrix fro loop working as good but when make a function it was return character no number and don't work

```
# this for loop is goog
S_values <- matrix("list", nrow(d_L))
for(i in 1: nrow(d_L)) {
    S_values[i] = shapiro.test(d_L[i,])$p.value
}
```

```
# the function from loop not work
shapiro_test_rows<- function(input, output ) {
  output <- matrix("list", nrow(input))

  for(i in 1: nrow(input)) {
    output[i] = shapiro.test(input[i,])$p.value
  }
}
  
shapiro_test_rows(d_L, S_values )
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to `return(output)` in the function i..e just before the outer closing `}`,

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Can you show the exact issue `it didn't work` is very generic and could be considered as many reasons

Comment: You don't need the `output` argument because you are creating it inside

Comment: S_value not created

Comment: This is what I get `set.seed(24)
d_L <- matrix(rnorm(5 * 4), 5, 4);shapiro_test_rows(d_L)[,1]
[1] "0.806971940138566"  "0.0462406276029567" "0.602353840880801"  "0.692893270682741"  "0.998560063995041"`

Comment: Why not do `S_values <- shapiro_test_rows(d_L)`. What you are trying inside is to `assign` new objects in the global env, instead return the output from function and assign it with `<-` to `S_values`

Comment: I need make function to apply again in my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to create objects in the global env, use `assign`, though it is not recommended

```
shapiro_test_rows<- function(input, output ) {
  out <- deparse(substitute(output))
  output <- matrix("list", nrow(input))

  for(i in 1:nrow(input)) {
    output[i] = shapiro.test(input[i,])$p.value
  }
  assign(out, output, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

-testing

```
> shapiro_test_rows(d_L, S_values)
> S_values
     [,1]                
[1,] "0.806971940138566" 
[2,] "0.0462406276029567"
[3,] "0.602353840880801" 
[4,] "0.692893270682741" 
[5,] "0.998560063995041"
```

---

The output is `character` matrix because of the way the output object was initialized - i.e. the `list` is not doing what it should be intended

```
str(matrix("list", 5))
 chr [1:5, 1] "list" "list" "list" "list" "list"
```

Creates a `character` matrix` with element as "list"

instead we could simply create a `matrix`

```
shapiro_test_rows<- function(input, output ) {
  out <- deparse(substitute(output))
  output <- matrix(nrow = nrow(input))

  for(i in 1: nrow(input)) {
    output[i] = shapiro.test(input[i,])$p.value
  }
  assign(out, output, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

-testing

```
> shapiro_test_rows(d_L, S_values)
> 
> S_values
           [,1]
[1,] 0.80697194
[2,] 0.04624063
[3,] 0.60235384
[4,] 0.69289327
[5,] 0.99856006
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
d_L <- matrix(rnorm(5 * 4), 5, 4)
```